# MS SQL, DB STARTUP блокирует процессы

Tags: sql-server, восстановление

Доброго времени суток.

Пытаюсь выполнить проверку и исправление поврежденной таблицы, но получаю в ответ

Check statement aborted. Database contains deferred transactions.

В ходе исследований удалось выяснить, что всему виной висящий уже долгое время процесс с SPID 5 и командой DB STARTUP, однако dbcc opentran показывает, что активных транзакций нет, dbcc inputbuffer для этого процесса не показывает ничего, а логи говорят, что восстановление шло и успешно завершилось.

Попытки перевести базу в single_user, emergency или offline закончились неудачей. Перезагрузка не помогает. Из бекапа база развернута уже в таком состоянии и использовать какие-то более ранние нет возможности.

Гугл не дает какого-то внятного совета. Надеюсь на вашу помощь.

Спасибо.

Comment: UPD: перезапустил сервер, следил за процесом recovery - после сообщеня об откате 500к транзакций, новых сообщений уже не поступает. Но теперь у меня 2 процесса DB STARTUP, второй заблокирован первым